# Custom byte cipher

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

I posted a custom byte cipher on this site a few months back, and after spending three days recoding it from scratch, wanted to post it again to see if you can offer any improvements. (I am not looking for: "You should use var instead of explicit declaration". I'm looking for significant code improvements, not coding style improvements.)

The base concept of my cipher works a little like a Caesar cipher, except it also includes a few "twists".

```
using System.Text;

namespace DreamforceFramework.Framework.Cryptography
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DreamforceByteCipher
    /// Gordon Kyle Wallace, "Krythic"
    /// Copyright (C) 2015 Gordon Kyle Wallace, "Krythic" - All Rights Reserved
    /// </summary>
    public static class DreamforceByteCipher
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts a string into a byte array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static byte[] Encrypt(string data, string password)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            string passwordHash = DreamforceHashing.GenerateSHA256(password);
            byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordHash);
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            bool shiftFlag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                int shift = hashedPasswordBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
                bytes[i] = shift <= 128
                    ? (byte)(data[i] + (shiftFlag
                        ? (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)
                        : (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)))
                    : (byte)(data[i] - (shiftFlag
                        ? (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)
                        : (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)));
                passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % 64;
                shiftFlag = !shiftFlag;
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts a byte array back into a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Decrypt(byte[] data, string password)
        {
            string passwordHash = DreamforceHashing.GenerateSHA256(password);
            byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordHash);
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            bool shiftFlag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                int shift = hashedPasswordBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
                data[i] = shift <= 128
                    ? (byte)(data[i] - (shiftFlag
                        ? (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)
                        : (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)))
                    : (byte)(data[i] + (shiftFlag
                        ? (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)
                        : (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)));
                passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % 64;
                shiftFlag = !shiftFlag;
            }
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention the speed. This algorithm can Read, Encrypt, and Decrypt Huckleberry Finn in a total time of roughly (00:00:00.1157119).

Comment: Just a heads up that, while you've put "All rights reserved" in your code comments, any content posted to Stack Exchange sites is [licensed Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 3):

The bodies of methods are strikingly similar. In fact, you can make the similarity even more striking by reverting the `shift <= 128` condition (and swapping branches, of course) in `Decrypt`:

```
            data[i] = shift > 128
                ? (byte)(data[i] + (shiftFlag
                    ? (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)
                    : (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)))
                : (byte)(data[i] - (shiftFlag
                    ? (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)
                    : (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)));
```

Now the difference is literally in one operator. I don't know idiomatic way to pass the operator into a method as a parameter (honestly I don't know `C#` whatsoever) - but I have no doubt there is. Lambda perhaps?

That done, you may factor out the non-DRY part into a helper method:

```
    byte[] transform(byte[] data, string password, operator compare)
    {
        string passwordHash = DreamforceHashing.GenerateSHA256(password);
        byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordHash);
        int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
        bool shiftFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            int shift = hashedPasswordBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
            data[i] = compare(shift)
                ? (byte)(data[i] + (shiftFlag
                    ? (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)
                    : (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)))
                : (byte)(data[i] - (shiftFlag
                    ? (byte)(((shift << 4)) % 255)
                    : (byte)(((shift << 2)) % 255)));
            passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % 64;
            shiftFlag = !shiftFlag;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

and call it from both `Encrypt` and `Decrypt`.

Comment: If I am reading your suggestion correctly(I am on my phone), the code you presented now has no way of decrypting the data. If you look at the code, there is the initial +/- branch. This IS different for both functions.

Comment: @Krythic Honestly I don't know what is this initial branch. Could you be more specific?

Comment: "[i] + (shiftFlag" is different for both functions. Decrypt is inverted.

Comment: @Krythic Exactly. I inverted the meaning of comparison, and swapped branches. It is an invariant rewrite. Semantically it is identical to original.

Comment: You aren't seeing what I'm talking about. You didn't invert the right thing, or leave an option for it to be inverted. All you did was change the initial branch, which tested for byte-half as a makeshift conditional for which path to take. It wouldn't decrypt.

Comment: @vnp - I get what you're saying, but I can also understand why Krythic is missing it.... Krythic, vnc is recommending just one function that does both encryption, and depcryption, depending on what operator you pass in to the method's `compare` argument.

Comment: @rolfl I understand the core of his suggestion; one function to rule them all. I was just trying to articulate that his implementation is flawed.